# Change pdf viewer for downloads in chromium browser

Tags: 12.04, google-chrome, chromium, okular

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and Chromium browser version 32.0.1700.102.

When I download pdf files in chromium I get a button in the bottom left corner of the window, like this:

[image]

If I click the button, the pdf file is opened in `evince`.
How can I change that to another pdf viewer, like `okular`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to change default `.pdf` viewer in the system simply mouse right click on a filename.pdf choose `properties` navigate to `open with` and see what is default application is set and replace it with desired one.

Comment: you're welcome you can also install Ubuntu Tweak and in section admins/file type manager you'll see all the file types and applications they open with.

Comment: You can also do some of that from the 'Details' settings program.